# Cost keeps on increasing in Multinomial logistic regression, instead of reducing

Tags: regression, logistic, matlab, multinomial-distribution

I am trying to implement multinomail logistic regression using gradient descent, following http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Softmax_Regression

My data set has 7 ratings classes from 1 to 7. But after I implemented it the cost in the cost function keeps increasing in each iteration.

My costFunction:

```
function [ cost ] = costFunctionMultiNominal( inputX,resultY,weights,lambda)
%UNTITLED8 Calculates the cost for gradient descent,assumes inputX has one
%additional feature for constant and Weights is a classes X features matrix

[rows,cols] = size(inputX);
numOfClasses = size(weights,1);
summation = 0;
for i=1:rows
    classLevelSummation = 0;
    %display(size(inputX));
    %display(size(weights));
    for j=1:numOfClasses
        multipliedMatrix = inputX(i,:)*weights';
        multipliedMatrix = bsxfun(@minus, multipliedMatrix, max(multipliedMatrix));
        if resultY(i)==j
            denominatorSum = 0;
            for l=1:numOfClasses

                denominatorSum = denominatorSum + exp(multipliedMatrix(l));
                display(denominatorSum);

            end

           classLevelSummation = classLevelSummation +  multipliedMatrix(j) - log(denominatorSum);
        end
    end
    summation = summation + classLevelSummation;
end
display(summation);
% Adding weight decay
WeightSq= 0;
for i=1:numOfClasses
    colSummation = 0;
    for j=1:cols
        colSummation = colSummation + weights(i,j)^2;
    end
    WeightSq = WeightSq +colSummation;
end
cost = summation/(-rows) + lambda*WeightSq*0.5;
end
```

calculatingPOfJ :

```
function [ result,resultVector ] = calculatePofJMultiNominal( inputX,Weights,j )
%UNTITLED11 Assume inputX is padded with one extra column for constant and
%has only one row, resultVector will only be returned if k=-1 and contain
%all the probabilties
numOfClasses = size(Weights,1);
resultVector = zeros(numOfClasses,1);
result = 0;
denominatorSum = 0;
multipliedMatrix = inputX*Weights';
%display(multipliedMatrix);
multipliedMatrix = bsxfun(@minus, multipliedMatrix, max(multipliedMatrix));
%display(multipliedMatrix);
            for l=1:numOfClasses

                denominatorSum = denominatorSum + exp(multipliedMatrix(l));
            end
%display(denominatorSum);
if j == -1
 for k=1:numOfClasses
       resultVector(k)= exp(multipliedMatrix(k))/(denominatorSum);
 end
else          
    result =  exp(multipliedMatrix(j))/(denominatorSum);
end

end
```

Comment: I really do not think anyone is going to read your code and debug it. However, here are two common pitfalls: (i) have you checked your derivatives with finite differences? (ii) Have you used smaller learning rates? Something like 0.0001?

Comment: Yes and yes, I think I am missing something really small, that is making the cost go up rather than down

Comment: Could you be calculating the (log) likelihood instead of the loss? The standard loss function for logistic regression is the negative log likelihood, so if you are maximizing positive log likelihood, that would be equivalent.